# Android action bar never splits on 5.1" screen

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In a sample app I populate the action bar with several items (with `android:showAsAction="always"`) and enabled `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` on the application in the manifest file.

On a 3.7" virtual device, the action bar gets split, even with only one item.

On a 5.1" virtual device (same as XPeria Z), the action bar **never** splits, whatever the number of items, which causes the title to be fully hidden at some point.

[image]
[image]

Why ? Is the action bar just not splittable at all on screens bigger than 5" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why ?

The request is `splitActionBarWhenNarrow`, and apparently 5.1" in portrait is not considered narrow. Since this is into the `-large` screen size bucket, this is not surprising.

Comment: which means I have no way to ask for the action bar to be split on this device, right ?

Comment: @fiddler: AFAIK, you are correct. You are welcome to skip `splitActionBarWhenNarrow` and create your own buttons at the bottom of the screen, to simulate a split action bar, though IMHO this will look goofy (particularly on tablets or in landscape mode).